# Increment Margin Top each time function is called

Tags: jquery, margin, increment

I am trying to increment my margin-top each time my function is called. Shouldn't this work?

```
$('.btn-default').css("marginTop", parseInt($(this).css("marginTop") +=28));
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery's `$.fn.css` method (as of jQuery 1.6) you only need to pass in the relative values portion. It will determine the base value for you:

```
$(".btn-default").css("marginTop", "+=28");
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value